# Cant connect to PosgreSQL through PG Admin: "Peer authentication failed"

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

While I try to connect to Postgres through PGAdmin I get the following error:

```
Error connecting to the server: 
FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "postgres"
```

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PostgreSQL

Answer (score 3):

You're trying to use `peer` authentication (the default for unix sockets) from a user other than the user identity you are connecting as.

You could:

- Create a user with the same name as your unix user and connect as that;
- Change the authentication mode in `pg_hba.conf`;
- `ALTER USER postgres PASSWORD 'blah'` then connect over TCP/IP with `md5` password authentication by filling in the hostname and password fields

For more information see [the Ubuntu docs on their PostgreSQL install](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PostgreSQL) (I'm assuming you're using Ubuntu since you didn't say) and the PostgreSQL documentation on client authentication.